Strmzi 0.26.0 on GKE (version - 1.30.5-gke.1014001) - poddisruptionbudgets not found
we have Strimzi 0.26.0 deployed on GKE (version - 1.30.5-gke.1014001)
resources - Kafka, KafkaBrodge, KafkaUser are now showing error due to - poddisruptionbudgets not found
kubectl describe kafka versa-kafka-gke -n kafka

Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-10-16T23:47:20.582Z
    Message:               Failure executing: POST at: https://10.44.0.1/apis/policy/v1beta1/namespaces/kafka/poddisruptionbudgets. Message: the server could not find the requested resource. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=404, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=null, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=the server could not find the requested resource, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=NotFound, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
    Reason:                KubernetesClientException
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NotReady
  Observed Generation:     29
Events:                    <none>

Error in the strimzi operator pod :
2024-10-17 18:27:20 WARN  AbstractOperator:481 - Reconciliation #502876(timer) Kafka(kafka/versa-kafka-gke): Failed to reconcile
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://10.44.0.1/apis/policy/v1beta1/namespaces/kafka/poddisruptionbudgets. Message: the server could not find the requested resource. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=404, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=null, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=the server could not find the requested resource, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=NotFound, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:693) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:672) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:625) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:565) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:526) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:314) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:754) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:89) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:61) ~[io.fabric8.kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar:?]
    at io.strimzi.operator.common.operator.resource.AbstractResourceOperator.internalCreate(AbstractResourceOperator.java:273) ~[io.strimzi.operator-common-0.26.0.jar:0.26.0]
    at io.strimzi.operator.common.operator.resource.AbstractResourceOperator.lambda$reconcile$0(AbstractResourceOperator.java:111) ~[io.strimzi.operator-common-0.26.0.jar:0.26.0]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159) ~[io.vertx.vertx-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100) ~[io.vertx.vertx-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157) ~[io.vertx.vertx-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [io.netty.netty-common-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]

Kafka, KafkaBridge & KafkaUsers are not showing as ready due to these issues,
btw, these services were up till yesterday when we did a rolling restart of the entity operator
Logs from Kafka pods show SSL connectivity issues which might be related to the KafkaBridge/KafkaUser going down
2024-10-17 19:04:53,146 INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.142.0.103 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-14]
2024-10-17 19:04:53,195 INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.142.0.15 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-13]
2024-10-17 19:04:53,207 INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.40.1.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
2024-10-17 19:04:53,230 INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.40.1.240 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(REPLICATION-9091)-SSL-4]
2024-10-17 19:04:53,310 INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.142.0.103 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-13]
2024-10-17 19:04:53,365 INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.40.1.240 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(REPLICATION-9091)-SSL-5]


From what i understand, Strimzi 0.26.0 references the deprecated 'policy/v1beta1' API for PDBs, while Kubernetes 1.30 has deprecated 'policy/v1beta1' .. so that is resulting in this issues i.e. Strimzi is attempting to check for PDB using apiVersion 'policy/v1beta1' which is not supported in Kubernetes 1.30
Is my understanding correct ?
What do i need to do to get the cluster running ?
Do i need to upgrade the cluster ? is there a quick-fix that can be done ?
Pls let me know!
thanks!

You have to upgrade your Strimzi cluster or downgrade your Kubernetes version. 0.26.0 is over 3 years old and Kubernetes 1.30 never existed when it was released.
